# Why is Rails Console command not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

thank you for taking the time to read this. I'm **extremely** new to this, and am currently following a textbook for learning Rails, so apologies if I'm slow to pick up instruction. Most of the obstacles I've come across I'm able to either google and click around, but I'm afraid I'm at a standstill with this one. And yes, I did poke around here for similar questions/answers, those didn't help either.

The command **$ Rails Console** doesn't work. Now, before inputting this command, I did try to input the **$ nano  ~/.irbrc** , and I don't know if I did that step correctly, and I don't know if that affects the $ Rails Console command. Prior to this, I also input **$ Spring Stop** — even before that, I was still receiving the same error, but I digress.

Here's what happens when I input the console command:

```
    ubuntu:~/environment $ cd sample_app
ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (master) $ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 2921
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        44: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        43: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        42: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        41: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        40: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        39: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        38: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        37: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
        36: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
        35: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:215:in `block in serve'
        34: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
        33: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
        32: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
        31: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
        30: from /home/ubuntu/environment/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
        29: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        28: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        27: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        26: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        25: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        24: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        23: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        22: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        21: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        20: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        19: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        18: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        17: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
        16: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
        15: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
        14: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:376:in `start'
        13: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/init.rb:20:in `setup'
        12: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/init.rb:228:in `run_config'
        11: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
        10: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
         9: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/.irbrc:11:in `<main>'
         8: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
         7: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         6: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         5: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         4: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         3: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         2: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:40:in `<main>'
         1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load': /home/ubuntu/.irbrc:4: unterminated regexp meets end of file (SyntaxError)
...conf[:AUTO_INDENT_MODE] = false
...
```

At this point, should I just start over from scratch? Is there a way to fix this at all? Much appreciated you guys!

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/.irbrc:4: unterminated regexp meets end of file (SyntaxError)`

Comment: Okay, what does this mean then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your `/home/ubuntu/.irbrc` file. This means that there is code that is not correctly formatted and can not be parsed by Ruby. When consuming your file, Ruby thinks that there is an unfinished regex, but it could just be an invalid character/formatting that looks like an unfinished rexex. At any rate, you need to inspect the contents of that file, to determine if the logic contained therein is what you expect.